# Как игнорировать пробелы при поиске совпадения в массиве строк

Tags: javascript, массивы

Функция должна искать значение в массиве строк и возвращать массив если есть значение и -1 если нет.

Строки могут содержать пробелы, их нужно игнорировать, только non-spaces символы имеют значение.

Не могу понять как дополнить функцию условием чтоб игнорировались пробелы.

```
let arr= ['a' , 'bc' , 'bcd' , 't est']

const find = (arr, value) => {

     if (arr.indexOf) {
         return arr.indexOf(value);
     }

     for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         if (arr[i] === value)
             return i;
     }
        return -1;
};

find(arr , "test");
```

Comment: @Dima Разве где то запрещалось задавать вопросы? Даже опытные разработчики гуглят.
Никто не рождается со знаниями. Мне кажется самое главное это решить задачу.
Ну и не копипастить а разобраться в вопросе, в моем случае копну  в регулярки поглубже.
Тем более часть функционала я написал сам...

Answer (score 1):

Заменяйте пробелы на пустую строку.

```js
let arr = ['a', 'bc', 'bcd', 't est']

const find = (arr, value) => {

 /* это проверяет не то, что Вы думаете
 if (arr.indexOf) {
   return arr.indexOf(value);
 }*/

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].replace(/ /g, "") === value)
      return i;
  }
  return -1;
};

console.log(find(arr, "test"));
```